# mysql Stored function not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the first flight of today. For that I'm using

```
delimiter//
CREATE function get_flightID(flightident())
returns int
begin
return (SELECT * FROM flightdep where depday = dayofweek(CURDATE()) ORDER BY depTime asc LIMIT 1;)
end//
delimiter;
```

But this isn't working. When I execute this I got an error about MySQL syntax.

> 17:50:50  ) end// delimiter   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') end// delimiter' at line 1   0.000 sec

I'm  really guessing what to use in my first line, I tried everything I could think of.

```
CREATE function get_flightID(flightident())
```

Comment: Add the error message please.

Comment: Why is flightident() in your function definition? It is not used anywhere in the body of the function. Take that out.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are returning `select *`, which would presumably have more than one column.  Second, you have an unnecessary semicolon.  Try something like this:

```
delimiter//
CREATE function get_flightID(flightident())
returns int
begin
    return (SELECT deptime
            FROM flightdep
            where depday = dayofweek(CURDATE())
            ORDER BY depTime asc
            LIMIT 1
           )
end//
delimiter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to return a resultset (that is, `SELECT *...`) from your function, but you declared it to return an `int`.

You want something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_flightID $$
CREATE function get_flightID()
    returns int
    reads sql data
    begin
        declare result int;

        SELECT flightID INTO result
          FROM flightdep 
         where depday = dayofweek(CURDATE())
         ORDER BY depTime asc LIMIT 1;

         return result;
    end$$
DELIMITER ;
```